# Sitecore "random" Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, sitecore, device, nullreferenceexception

I was working fine with sitecore 6.5 when suddenly this morning I came to work, did a get latest version and then this error started

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Editors.Folder.FolderPage.Render() +358
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +70
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +189
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3177
```

also, some times I am getting this error when opening folders:

```
>    [InvalidOperationException: The Sitecore.Client.Device is null.]
>     Sitecore.Client.get_Device() +86    Sitecore.UIUtil.GetBrowserClassString() +326   
> Sitecore.sitecore.login.LoginPage.AddBrowserAttributes() +135   
> Sitecore.sitecore.login.LoginPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +435   
> System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +113   
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>         +4297
```

Any idea how to fix it ??

Comment: can you try other browser? did you have this problem before getting latest?

Comment: @MarekMusielak I have tried on FF, Chrome and IE. Same error. I did not have this problem after. I  have one coworker with the same error

Comment: can you try to clear your cookies and caching and check again

Comment: @SitecoreClimber done, still the same error on FF, on IE when login it just redirects me to the same page. I also tried on incognito mode / private browsing

Comment: If you didn't have this problem before getting latest, check what was changed since your last update. It must be something added recently to your project.

Comment: FYI I just had this happen on a 8.0 site.

Answer (score 4):

We just had this happen too. Solved by restarting the site. Not sure what caused it.